# Remove list elements at given indices

Tags: c#, list

I have a list which contains some items of type string.

```
List<string> lstOriginal;
```

I have another list which contains idices which should be removed from first list.

```
List<int> lstIndices;
```

I'd tried to do the job with **RemoveAt()** method ,

```
foreach(int indice in lstIndices)
{
     lstOriginal.RemoveAt(indice);
}
```

but it crashes and said me that **"index is Out of Range."**

Comment: where are the list of indices coming from? because you delete indices that aren't in the list

Comment: When you remove an item, it changes the indices of items that come after it. If you have indices 1 and 3, when you remove one, index 3 no longer points to the same object. It could now be out of bounds, which is why you get that exception.

Comment: This is crashing because when you remove the first item from the list, all of the indices change accordingly.

Comment: When is the lstIndices populated?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to sort the indexes that you would like to return from largest to smallest in order to avoid removing something at the wrong index.

```
foreach(int indice in lstIndices.OrderByDescending(v => v))
{
     lstOriginal.RemoveAt(indice);
}
```

Here is why: let's say have a list of five items, and you'd like to remove items at indexes `2` and `4`. If you remove the item at `2` first, the item that was at index `4` would be at index `3`, and index `4` would no longer be in the list at all (causing your exception). If you go backwards, all indexes would be there up to the moment when you're ready to remove the corresponding item.

Comment: This would work but it would be mo efficient to go in a for loop over the indices, and removing index-i

Comment: @YoryeNathan that assumes that the indexes in the list are already in ascending order.  If they're unordered you need to do some type of sort.

Comment: @Servy If the indices to remove are not sortd, it won't work eother way. He must sort them in both ways, unless he knows that they are in order. IF they are ALREADY in descending order, then a simple loop will do, but then he wouldn't have this problem so this is not the case anywyas.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I'm rather sure that this code will work even if the indexes are not sorted at all.  The indexes need to be removed in order of highest to lowest, this sort ensures that.  Do you somehow thing it would be advantageous to do an ascending sort and then iterate backwards?  Why bother?  Also note that the sort implementation (quicksort) is optimized to run in the best case when the data to sort is already in sorted or reverse sorted order.

Comment: @Servy What I meant is that your approach also sorts them, technically. I'm only saying that if the OP knows that the indices to remove are sorted ascending, it is better to simply loop backwards, or loop normally and remove index-i.

Comment: @YoryeNathan well of course an orderby call sorts the data.  If it's merely performance considerations,  as I said, the sort algorithm used is optimized for that case, so it will have O(n) performance.  Additionally no need to prematurely optimize.  Obvious correctness and code simplicity/readability is more than worth it unless the data is huge.  If there really are performance consideration the whole design should be re-considered.

Answer (score 6):

How are you populating the list of indices?  There's a much more efficient `RemoveAll` method that you might be able to use.  For example, instead of this:

```
var indices = new List<int>();
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in data)
    if (SomeFunction(data))
        indices.Add(index++);

//then some logic to remove the items
```

you could do this:

```
data.RemoveAll(item => SomeFunction(item));
```

This minimizes the copying of items to new positions in the array; each item is copied only once.

You could also use a method group conversion in the above example, instead of a lambda:

```
data.RemoveAll(SomeFunction);
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason this is happening is because when you remove an item from the list, the index of each item after it effectively decreases by one, so if you remove them in increasing index order and some items near the end of the original list were to be removed, those indices are now invalid because the list becomes shorter as the earlier items are removed.

The easiest solution is to sort your index list in decreasing order (highest index first) and then iterate across that.

Answer (score 5):

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices.Count; i++)
{
    items.RemoveAt(indices[i] - i);
}
```

Comment: This assumes the list is sorted in ascending order.  In that case, would be more efficient to do `for (int i = indices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)`.  Why is that?  Because the items *after* the index have to be copied to the previous position.  There's less copying if you start at the end than if you start at the beginning, because if you start at the beginning, you're also copying items that you are about to remove.

Comment: this is good answer. But the list should be sorted. Thank you Yorye Nathan

Comment: Reallocation will not differ between these approaches, but your loop is indeed more readable. And of course, you do one less atomic calculation, so perfectionalism calls you to win.

Comment: @meorfi in writing my previous comment, I remembered the `RemoveAll` method, which reduces the copying overhead even further.  It's not clear from the question whether it can be applied here, however.

Answer (score 2):

My in-place deleting of given indices as handy extension method. It copies all items only once so it is much more performant if large amount of indicies is to be removed.

It also throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in case where index to remove is out of bounds.

```
 public static class ListExtensions 
 {
    public static void RemoveAllIndices<T>(this List<T> list, IEnumerable<int> indices)
    {
        //do not remove Distinct() call here, it's important
        var indicesOrdered = indices.Distinct().ToArray();
        if(indicesOrdered.Length == 0)
            return;

        Array.Sort(indicesOrdered);

        if (indicesOrdered[0] < 0 || indicesOrdered[indicesOrdered.Length - 1] >= list.Count)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        int indexToRemove = 0;
        int newIdx = 0;

        for (int originalIdx = 0; originalIdx < list.Count; originalIdx++)
        {
            if(indexToRemove < indicesOrdered.Length && indicesOrdered[indexToRemove] == originalIdx)
            {
                indexToRemove++;
            }
            else
            {
                list[newIdx++] = list[originalIdx];
            }
        }

        list.RemoveRange(newIdx, list.Count - newIdx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var array = lstOriginal.ConvertAll(item => new int?(item)).ToArray();
        lstIndices.ForEach(index => array[index] = null);
        lstOriginal = array.Where(item => item.HasValue).Select(item => item.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 lstIndices.OrderByDescending(p => p).ToList().ForEach(p => lstOriginal.RemoveAt((int)p));
```

As a side note, in foreach statements, it is better not to modify the Ienumerable on which foreach is running. The out of range error is probably as a result of this situation.

Comment: This is incorrect: the out of range error is a result of the fact that removing items changes the index of other items, and this solution doesn't fix that.  For example, suppose you wanted to remove the items at indexes 5 and 6.  You could either call `RemoveAt(6)` and `RemoveAt(5)`, in that order, or you could call `RemoveAt(5)` and `RemoveAt(5)` in that order.

Comment: @phoog you may be right on this context, on the otherhand, it is better not to modify the enumerable in a foreach loop on which same list is enumerated.

Comment: @daryal It's not modifying the list that's being enumerated.  There are two lists.  The one being enumerated is different than the one being modified.