# Remove List items given a list of indices

Tags: c#, list

I have an `List`, i.e. `[0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 0.5]`. How can I do a `RemoveRange` by giving a list of indices to be removed from the original list, i.e. `[0, 4, 2, 7, 8]`?.

The `List(T).RemoveRange` cannot work in my case, because it is defined as

```
public void RemoveRange(int index, int count)
```

Also I do not wish to use a `for` loop and check the list iteratively. Is there any other way?

Comment: Do these indices have anything in-common?

Comment: not really...just List<int>

Comment: Why no for loop, and what have you tried? Anyway see [Remove list elements at given indices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908564/how-to-remove-from-a-list-some-items-c-sharp).

Comment: Is the list of indices unoredered (as is suggested by your question)?

Comment: Any explanation for the downvotes, or just a habit of downvoting without explanation?

Comment: @Nostradamus, not a downvoter, Just got here. But I'm guessing it's a lack of research effort (due to the duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ's [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) to keep all which are not in the index-list:

```
list = list.Where((d, index) => !indices.Contains(index)).ToList();
```

Another "less elegant"  approach would be to use a backwards loop and `List.RemoveAt`:

```
indices.Sort();
for (int i = indices.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list.RemoveAt(indices[i]);
```

Comment: @CodeCaster: now it's better, my first approach was backwards looping the whole collection instead of only the indices list.